# Change Display Mode on CTRL-ALT-DEL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx, dxgi

There seems to be a bit of a quirk with Window's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.  When a D3D11 window in exclusive fullscreen mode loses focus via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, the desktop retains the display mode used by this window.  If the resolution is too small, using the desktop becomes a bit obtuse.

I want to make sure that the desktop is returned to its former display mode on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, but there's no message for it and I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that with DXGI.  Is this possible?

Comment: Read [DirectX Graphics Infrastructure: Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025.aspx).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn This issue isn't addressed on that page.

Comment: Are you using ``MakeWindowAssociation``? What flags are you providing?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Yes, I'm using `DXGI_MWA_NO_WINDOW_CHANGES`, but I've tried letting dxgi handle everything itself and the same problem occurs.